# Linux Tomcat MySQL connection failure

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server running on Linux which access a remote MySQL server and, suddenly, without any change in configuration/programs or anything that I'm aware of, I started to get the following error trace:

```
SQLException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@12fd02da
 And the error stack is: 
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
 The driver has not received any packets from the server. 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:983) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:339) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2252) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:795) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327) 
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) 
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) 
 at com.localhost.AtW.servlets.Dispatcher.doGet(Dispatcher.java:66) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
 at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436) 
 at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) 
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) 
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) 
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) 
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) 
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host 
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) 
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) 
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) 
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) 
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214) 
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:298) ... 41 more
```

Also, I normally issue the Linux command `service iptables start` after booting the computer, which results in a mail being sent to the root stating that there were errors. Still everything worked OK till now.

Today, mails were also sent but, and this is quite strange too, the mails show a date of **tomorrow** even though when entering the command `date` I see the correct date and time. I don't know if there is any connection between the two things.

I have no idea what the issue is and where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by chance!!!

While the Linux machine has static IP, the machine on which MySQL is running was configured to use DHCP. It appears that the network switch was restarted and, by chance, that machine received a different IP and hence the TOMCAT was unable to communicate (wrong IP).

I know... I should had checked that before posting the question.

Anyway, this may be useful for somebody...